# Why is "?from=@" being appended to my url?

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, url, url-rewriting

My website, joshvickerson.com, keeps having the parameter "?from=@" added to the end of its url when navigating to the homepage. Oddly, if I remove it and hit enter in the address bar the page will reload without it.

My site used to be a simple PHP site but I just changed it to an angular app. This happened both when I was using PHP and now that I'm using Angular. It seems to only happen in Chrome. There are no longer any PHP files in the site's folder.

What could be causing this and how can I stop it from happening?

EDIT:

It still happens with a very basic index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    HELLO
  </body>
</html>
```

There are no PHP scripts in the site directory, nor do I have an .htaccess file in any directory for this site. The virtual host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin josh@joshvickerson.com
  ServerName  joshvickerson.com
  ServerAlias www.joshvickerson.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /path/to/site

  <Directory /path/to/site/>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /path/to/site/log/error.log
  CustomLog /path/to/site/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How should we know? Might be an apache rewrite rule, something in your PHP- or angular code or whatsoever. You provide none of that to us. Add more information plz.

Comment: On a sidenote: It happens in Firefox as well. To me that is. Try putting in a very basic index.html. If it still happens, you'll know it's not caused by a script and you'll need to search in other places, like your server settings (apache?). If it doesn't, you'll have to figure out which code is causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the DNS records were modified in my registrar somehow. There's a URL redirect record for the domain that includes the parameter string.

No idea how that go there, but this has resolved it. Not sure why it didn't occur to me sooner.

Comment: Weird! I use namecheap and the same thing happened to me. Good catch.

Comment: I have the same namecheap issue

Comment: same with namecheap

Answer (score 4):

It looks to be nginx redirect based.

If your site is accessed from `www.joshvickerson.com`, it is not redirected, however, if it is accessed from `joshvickerson.com`, "?from=@" is appended to the end of the url.

By inspecting the network requests you can see that `joshvickerson.com` returns a `302 Moved Temporarily` Status Code. This causes it to be redirected to `www.joshvickerson.com?from=@`

[image: Inspecting the Network Request]

EDIT: It looks like you are running Apache, even though in the Response Header, it lists `nginx/1.0.15` as the Server.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any ideas why that redirect happens and what I can do about it?

Comment: I'd check your apache config, should be somewhere in `/etc/apache2/` on Ubuntu. It also could be in a .htaccess file if you are on a shared hosting server.